# Clarify example of Faraday's law

Tags: electromagnetism

Im wondering if it is possible to induce a high voltage current (above 1k Volts), simply using a falling magnet and a copper wire  - it probably is, but then what does it take to do so.

I've done some small scale tests, with a small magnet, copper wire and trying to match the calculated (induced) current with the measured one. Without success though. Big difference between the measured and calculated. So I'm wondering if I haven't fully grasped Faraday's law of induction?

Let me give an example where I've chosen elements that theoretically induce a high voltage current in a conduction wire as of what I have understood of Faraday's law of induction.

Having this equation for Faraday's law:

$$E = (N * B * A) / \delta t$$
Where
E = Volts(emf)
N = Number of turns in the conducting wire
B = Tesla (Strength of magnet)
A = Area/Cross section of magnet in square meters ($m^2$)
$\delta t$ = Speed/change of induction (how fast the magnet i falling/passing through the copper coil.)

Found a copper coil that has **24K turns**.
A magnet (Neodymium N45), with a stregth of **1.32 Tesla**
The magnet is cylindrical and has a diameter of 1.75cm (Ø3cm), hence an area of: **0,00962 $m^2$**

I thought of dropping the magnet from 3 meters in the air (inside a pipe, to ensure it passes through the coil), and the gravitational force (9.8m/s2) will accelerate the magnet to a speed of 7,67 m/s after that 3 meter fall. I have intentionally ignored the fact that magnet probably would be slowed by "wind" and small bumps against the pipe.
The copper coil (cylindrical) is 10 cm high, hence the magnet will pass through the coil in about **0,01304 sec.**

Putting this in the above equation gives:

Volts(emf) = (24000 x 1,32 x 0,00962) / 0,013 = ~2.337 V AC

I then had a physicist throw a small note at me, saying: I should be cautious about applying Faraday's law in non-homogeneous field. However that was without elaboration, but couldn't tell what he meant by that.

What am I missing? - Besides I know the speed of the falling magnet will be less, because of friction in the tube and a few other factors.

Note: The magnet is kept in the vertical position, because of it's height, it can not flip around inside the tube.

Any clarification of my understanding of Faraday's law is much appreciated.

Comment: It could well be a practical point which is causing the disparity.  How did you attempt to measure the induced voltage?  If you tried to use a moving coil meter then your attempt at a measurement would have been doomed because the reaction time of such a meter is of the arder of tenths of seconds.  A digital voltmeter would also have a fairly long response time so perhaps you should us something with a shorter response time like a cathode ray oscilloscope (cro) or some sort of digital capture device linked to a computer?

Comment: The physicist meant that the algebraic formula you have used is a specific case of Faraday's Law; the general law is a differential equation, and requires calculus or numerical methods to solve.

Comment: That's pretty old technology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignition_magneto. The trick to making this work is to use the induction and to open a switch just at the right time.

Comment: Part of your problem here is that the falling magnet doesn't actually generate a voltage while it's inside the coil, it will only generate a signal while there is a change of flux trough the coil, which happens at the entry and at the exit. The second part is that all coils have a stray-capacitance, which forms a self-resonant circuit with the coil's inductance and a finite coil resistance. For systems like yours there will be a strong mismatch between the excitation waveform and the resulting low-pass/resonant circuit and that will greatly reduce the effective voltage.

Comment: @Farcher I used a digital multimeter like this: https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.monacor.dk/import/media/FLE/DMT2570.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiXsryx4eXNAhXK3SwKHaBLALoQFgg0MAA&usg=AFQjCNHvrrjEWNUaovjQVMeacTrof0BnGQ for the measuring. Yeah, this could very well be a contributing factor; the reaction time of measuring tool. Thanks, I was blind about that.

Comment: If you look at the specification page for your multimeter it says the measuring rate is 2.5 measurements per second.

Comment: @Farcher Yeah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. That explains why I some times didn't get a reading at all in my small scale experiments.

Comment: A side question or two. I guess it is important how the coil is wound; in straight horizontal curves, rather than being crossing multiple times, like from top of coil to bottom of coil multiple times? Or doesn't that matter at all?

Comment: The second side question: the rate of change of the magnetic field passing the coil, is that some correctly calculated? - taking into account that the time the change happens is; from just before the magnetic field of the magnet enters the coil until it exits the coil, and not the physical magnet and coil it self?

Comment: @CuriousOne Is that a "known" factor, like a constant or something I could apply to my equation depending on which conducting wire I am using? What level of mismatch should I expect? Half voltage measured compared to calculated, much less, or?

Comment: One can calculate that,it just doesn't come out "well" for the purposes of generating high voltage. First we have to transfer a significant amount of energy into the coil, i.e. there has to be a magnetic force acting on the falling magnet which slows it down. This is possible if there is a significant current flowing trough the coil, which is achieved by shorting a coil with relatively few turns (maybe hundreds), which causes a strong induced current. Now energy is being transferred into the coil, which then can be released as high voltage when the switch opens. That's what the magneto does.